# Git post-receive hook to clone and checkout two branches into two separate directories

Tags: git, hook, sh, githooks

I have a Git repository, and I need to write a `post-receive` script that checkouts two branches into two separate directories and then performs some actions. I have the following script that works for one branch, but I'm not sure how to script it so that it checks out two branches.

```
#!/bin/sh

GIT_REPO="$HOME/oliverjash.me.git"
TMP_GIT_CLONE="$HOME/tmp/oliverjash.me"
PUBLIC_WWW="/var/www/oliverjash.me"

# Clone & Checkout a copy of this repository somewhere
git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE

# Do other actions
cd $TMP_GIT_CLONE
compass compile -e $RAKE_ENV -c config.rb --force
jekyll $PUBLIC_WWW
cd $HOME
rm -rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
exit
```

Bear in mind that the "actions" I need to do to each copy will be the same except for the variables, of course – I would really like to avoid repeating code.

Comment: You would probably be better off having some other service do the work and just signal that service in the hook.

Comment: What like? I'm not sure if I understand.

Comment: Depending on how complex what you need to do is something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) will do what you want and is fairly simple to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use a shell that supports functions, you could create a function that takes the clone directory as an argument. You would just invoke the function twice, once for each clone directory. (This is assuming that you meant **clone** where you said **checkout** above, since I do not see a *git checkout* in your example.)

Comment: How do you clone a specific branch? I only need a copy of the files, I don't need the repository data, so that's why I wasn't sure whether I needed to clone or checkout.

Comment: You can only clone a whole repository with Git.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but in the end I came up with this.

```
#!/bin/bash --login

GIT_REPO="$HOME/oliverjash.me.git"

source "$HOME/.bash_profile"

checkout () {
  BRANCH="$1"
  TMP_GIT_CLONE="$2"
  PUBLIC_WWW="$3"

  git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
  cd $TMP_GIT_CLONE
  git checkout $BRANCH
  compass compile -e $RAKE_ENV -c config.rb --force
  jekyll $PUBLIC_WWW
  cd $HOME
  rm -rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
}

checkout master "$HOME/tmp/oliverjash.me" "/var/www/oliverjash.me"
checkout project "$HOME/tmp/project.oliverjash.me" "/var/www/project.oliverjash.me"

exit
```

I don't like how it recompiles every branch, even if changes have only been pushed to one, but it's good enough.